# S3 not booting up after being flashed with a stock ROM

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

I had an S3 with Cynogenmod and I'm flashing a stock rom from here:

http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/database/GT-I9300/#firmware

The process of flashing, with Odin3, works and in another S3 it worked without any issues, but in this particular one, when it boots, it goes through the process of applying some upgrades, then reboots and shows this:

[image]

Any ideas what's going on and/or what to do?

Comment: Can you go to download mode?

Comment: @NikolaK. yes, and I found a solution shortly after posting.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. I guess Cyanogenmod left something in /data that was interfering with the boot up process, maybe settings for a newer version of some app. Starting by pressing volume-up and home at the same time dropped me in the menu with the factory reset. Doing the factory reset allowed the phone to boot up properly.